# sybase max with ordery by not working

Tags: date, sql-order-by, max, sybase

My requirement is to get the max value of date field that is less than the given date. The table has data as

```
dt_start     |  dt_end  
-----------------------------
1 Jan 2013   | 31 March 2013  
1 April 2013 | 30 June 2013  
1 July 2013  | 30 Sep 2013  
1 Oct 2013   | 31 Dec 2013
```

so, for 25 July,2013 I should get 1 July, 2013.

After some iteration I do have the working query, but I am not able to understand why is it not working if I add the `order by` clause. I am doing a `order by` on other field as shown in below query.

```
select max(dt_start)
from 
     table1
where 
dt_start <= '2013-07-25'
--order by dt_end desc  --no result for long time if you include this stmt in query
```

Can you please explain why the query doesn't work if I add the `order by`?

Comment: Is there any value of `order by` when you want to get `max(dt_start)`?

Comment: I know, there is no value, and I have stated that. I am trying to understand the processing.

Comment: Ok, ordering on some other field is a sensible and legitimate query. I have updated the question. Using max on one field with order by on other is leading to same effect. @sarwar026 please check.

Comment: your updated query should work fine. I really unable to understand why it is not working and taking very long time!!